# Docker:Registry:Unable to pull from someone elses private registry

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I want to pull a docker image from someone else private registry[containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088]. When I am pulling a docker image I am getting this error

```
[root@bmcapp ~]# docker pull containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088/kafk-server:1
Error response from daemon: Get https://containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

1) I tried adding ca.crt certificate given by them at this folder  `/etc/docker/certs.d/containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088` .

2) Then in `docker.service` file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` , I tried adding 
--insecure-registry containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088
at this line in docker.service like this
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`

TO

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088
```

Then I restarted docker and daemon

```
[root@bmcapp ~]#systemctl daemon-reload


[root@bmcapp ~]#systemctl restart docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
```

CONFIGURATION:

```
[root@bm ~]# docker info
Containers: 113
 Running: 29
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 84
Images: 50
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
Kernel Version: 4.1.12-61.1.28.el7uek.x86_64
Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.3
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
```

Comment: Please tell how to add insecure registry with this config so that I will be able to pull. I have the certificate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to set the environment variable `DOCKER_OPTS` with the insecure registry, and **restart** the Docker daemon again.

```
export DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088"
```

Then, try login to the registry.

```
docker login containerregistry.us.xxxxx.com:8088
```

If you want the environment variable to stick, put it in your `bashrc` / `bash_profile`

A better way to do this is just use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to generate a valid SSL cert.